# Clarification on central limit theorem

Tags: central-limit-theorem

I found this definition of central limit theorem in the book: Intro to probability and statistics using R:
[image]

I thought the sample mean $\bar X$ itself followed the normal distribution and not the calculated quantity as shown.

Comment: (1) $\bar X$ never follows a normal distribution unless the population distribution is normal.  (2) The limiting distribution of $\bar X$ is a constant (the value $\mu$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the sample mean $\bar{X}$ approaches a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$, i.e. $\bar{X}\sim N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}) $ however if you standardize the sample mean (by writing it in the form in the question), you find that approaches a Normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$, i.e. $Z \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Welcome to CV! I suggest you replace "follows a normal distribution" with "approaches a normal distribution", since the CLT does not claim that the distribution is exact.

Comment: Thanks for that. (+1) Hope you continue contributing to our site.

Comment: In the context of "approaches", "$n$" is meaningless.

Comment: This answer is problematic, e.g. it's not true that $\bar X\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$. The distribution of $\bar X$ looks kinda like normal when $n$ is large.

Answer (score 5):

It's a very common mistake - which I make sometimes myself - to have the non-constant on the right hand side of the arrow:
$$f_n\to \mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$$, where $f_n$ is the probability distribution of $\bar X$.

Since your right hand side is changing, it's difficult to prove statements about this convergence relation, and I mean *impossible* by *difficult*.

Hence, we want to have the constant right hand side to apply our convergence proving tricks, e.g. $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ would be a non-changing distribution. So, we formulate the convergence statement using it:
$$Z=\frac{\bar X-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt n}\sim\tilde f_n$$, where $\tilde f_n$ - sequence of distributions (functions), which converges to the standard normal:
$$\tilde f_n\to\mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

This one we can handle: the right hand side is not changing, only the left hand side is.

It's still tempting to think about the distribution of $\bar X$ as one that *looks more and more like normal*, i.e. taking a shape of the normal distribution. However I wouldn't use the term *converges*, or even *approaches*, as they are *loaded* in mathematics. You'll run into people who will be confused with this language for they will expect to see the non changing right hand side.