# Central Limit Theorem and Confidence Interval

Tags: confidence-interval, central-limit-theorem

Let $\{X_n\}_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. RV's, where each $X_n$ is a copy of RV $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$. For $n > 0$, I can define $\bar X_n := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then, central limit theorem states that

$\bar X_n \sim \mathcal N(\mathbb E[X], \sigma^2/n)$.

Now, fix $n > 0$ and let us pick samples of size $n$, and suppose we pick $m$ samples $\{S_1, \cdots, S_m\}$. For each sample $S_k$, I can calculate (mean, variance), denoted by $(\hat \theta_k, \hat \sigma_k^2)$. Then, I construct confidence intervals $\{I_1, \cdots, I_m\}$, where $I_k = (\hat \theta_k - 2\sigma_k, \hat \theta_k + 2\sigma_k)$. Note that for each $k = 1, \cdots, m$, $\sigma_k$ will be different, i.e. each confidence interval would have different length.

Central limit theorem does not give me information about distribution of variances. Without a guarantee that each confidence interval has the same length, how am I guaranteed that 95% of confidence intervals would actually contain the true parameter $\mathbb E[X]$?

Comment: 1. The confidence intervals having the same length a) will never occur if the random variates are from a continuous distribution and b) is irrelevant.  2. Your definition of the central limit theorem is incorrect: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174734/clarification-on-central-limit-theorem?rq=1 for some clarification.

Comment: @James Your notation is off (among other things, you conflate standard deviations with estimates). With CIs write a pivotal quantity (or in this case an asymptotically pivotal quantity) and use not just CLT but also Slutsky's theorem to get a suitable distribution for the pivotal quantity, and hence the CI for the parameter. Different CIs dont need to have the same length, you just need 1-alpha of them to overlap the parameter.

Comment: @jbowman Would you elaborate why my definition of CLT is incorrect? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT

Comment: @JamesC Did you read [what Aksakal wrote](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/174755/247274) in the link by Jbowman? "Since your right hand side is changing, it's difficult to prove statements about this convergence relation, and I mean impossible by difficult." If so, what remains unclear?

Comment: @Dave so if I fix my statement as $\sqrt{n} \bar X_n \sim \mathcal N(\mathbb E[X], \sigma)$, then the statement becomes correct. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Dave Another question. Hope you don't mind. In practice, is there a $n$-value that we use to apply CLT? We know that $\sqrt n \bar X_n$ converges to a normal distribution, but we do not know how fast the convergence is.

Comment: @JamesC That sounds like a good topic for a new question to post separately. // You're getting closer when you have the $\sqrt n$ only on the left, but it is not quite right. The fully correct version would give some kind of arrow to denote convergence, perhaps even with a $d$ up top to denote convergence in distribution: $\sqrt n \bar X_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(\mathbb E\left[X\right], \sigma)$. The standard way to write the theorem would have the convergence be to $N(0,1)$, but that's just a matter of some algebra.

Comment: @Dave I see.  Thanks!